# Reflection for Finding Classes in Android Application

Tags: android, reflection, classloader

I want to find classes in a certain package for creating objects using reflection. So basically, I have working code for plain JAVA applications. The problem is that

`Package.getPackages()`

and

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(packageName);
```

does not seem to work for Android as I always get an empty array in the first case and null in the second. However, I tested the code in common JAVA using Unittests with the same test data and it worked.

Does anybody know a workaround? I know that there is a package manager, however I don't need a list of installed packages that refer to an APK. I want to enumerate all package URLs within an APK.

Regards,
Florian

Comment: What, precisely, do you think a "package URL" is?

Comment: To make myself more clear: With the package manager on Android, I can get a list of all installed packages. These packages (e.g. my.first.app) refer to android applications. So I know I can get those. However, I cannot use this code to get information about the internal package architecture. So for example, I have a second library inside my APK with a different pacakge structure (e.g. your.second.library) the package manager is not able to find this package. However, it is found using Package.getPackages() for desktop apps or unit tests. If required I can provide the entire working source?